# error messages disappear quickly when updating quantities on product detail page

Tags: magento2, ajax, messages, qty

error messages disappear quickly when updating quantities on the product detail page

I am using Magento 2.4.5
I have changed the code in the below files but there is no effect

/Magento_Ui/web/js/view/messages.js
module-ui/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html

Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js

could anyone please tell me how I can increase the time of error messages?

Answer (score 0):

In this file **vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js** you will find this code **hideTimeout: 5000**

Here 5000 = 5 seconds, so change accordingly and after that execute magento commands

Comment: i have increased the time in "onHiddenChange" function.

Comment: https://www.appsloveworld.com/magentocdng/63/magento-2-4-decline-message-disappears-quickly-several-quick-fixes-don39t-to?expand_article=1

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: ,thanks for update but i tried the same but did not work

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: if (isHidden) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(self.selector).hide('blind', {}, 500);
                }, 50000);
            }

Comment: This was solved in magento246 version, I am sharing that code try that code, check my updated answer and if it works please give up-vote

Answer (score 0):

magento245

```
onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
    // Hide message block if needed
    if (isHidden) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this.selector).hide('blind', {}, this.hideSpeed);
        }.bind(this), this.hideTimeout);
    }
}
```

magento246

```
onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
    // Hide message block if needed
    if (isHidden) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this.selector).hide('slow');
        }.bind(this), this.hideTimeout);
    }
}
```